# Swift - How to stop form from resetting after returning from another segue

Tags: ios, swift, forms

I have a form that is initialised with values from an core data object. The form has a button with an image that goes to another view controller where it can pick other pictures to set as the image. after choosing an image the view goes back to the form but the previously loaded information as been reset.

Form code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.gender.dataSource = self;
    self.gender.delegate = self;

    profilePic.setImage(UIImage(named: imgArray[row])!, forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    fName.text = friend.firstName!;
    lName.text = friend.lastName!;
    mobile.text = friend.mobile!;
    address.text = friend.address!;
    if (friend.gender == "Male")
    {
        gender.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true);
    }
    else
    {
        gender.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true);
    }
}
```

button click code:

```
@IBAction func profilePicClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("picList") as! PicListTableViewController
    nextViewController.viewCaller = "edit";
    self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

picture list returning code:

```
if (viewCaller == "edit")
{
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editFriend") as! EditFriendViewController
    nextViewController.row = indexPath.row;
    nextViewController.n = 1;
    self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

everything functions correctly its only the form resting after returning from choosing a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't return to the previous view controller, but rather present a new one. Try this in your returning method:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In addition to this you should pass a selected image back to your original view controller. You can achivieve this by using delegate pattern (call a delegate method as soon as you pick an image on your modal view controller)